# How to run meteor in the background forever

Tags: meteor

Currently I ssh to the linux server and type in the following to start the meteor:
nohub meteor &

But as soon as I terminate the ssh session to the linux server, meteor goes down.

How do I run meteor run forever even after terminating the ssh session?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89483/keeping-a-process-running-after-putty-or-terminal-has-been-closed

Comment: You should probably deploy a built version of the app to your server, not run a development server on your production machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) in my Meteor app.